# does Highstock support a right border for a panel (yAxis)?

Tags: highcharts

does Highstock support a right border for a panel (yAxis)? Right now, i can draw only left, top and down border.
Attached an image to describe my question

[image]

Comment: Plot borders can go on all sides: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/chart/plotborder/.  What does your chart configuratiion look like?

Comment: Plot border connect all YAxis panels, but i need to draw a border for the yAxis with empty space between panels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a couple more yAxis that aren't attached to a series.

```
        yAxis: [{
            labels: {
                align: 'right',
                x: -3
            },
            title: {
                text: 'OHLC'
            },
            height: '60%',
            lineWidth: 2,
            opposite: false
        }, {
            labels: {
                align: 'right',
                x: -3
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Volume'
            },
            top: '65%',
            height: '35%',
            offset: 0,
            lineWidth: 2,
            opposite: false
        },{
            height: '60%',
            lineWidth: 2
        }, {

            top: '65%',
            height: '35%',
            offset: 0,
            lineWidth: 2
        }],
```

http://jsfiddle.net/blaird/6oy17bhu/

Comment: I contacted HighChart support team and they offer two answers, first answer is your answer! Thank you

Comment: Another answer is by drawing a right border using renderer object, http://jsfiddle.net/sfgrc8jj/1/